# Naming an Ion with respect to its oxidation state

Tags: notation

When identifying compounds, where certain elements are in various oxidation states we write the oxidation state in Roman numbers after it. Does the same go for ions? What would the correct way of writing Cu$^{2+}$ in words be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the same go for ions? What would the correct way of writing $\ce{Cu^2+}$ in words be?

The most common way of saying $\ce{Cu^{2+}} $ would be "copper(II) ion".  However keep in mind that in aqueous solution, [various ligands bind](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/3_d-Block_Elements/Group_11%3A_Transition_Metals/Chemistry_of_Copper) to naked copper(II) ions forming various complexes.  So for example "hexaaquacopper(II)" ions are very common.  In these names the charge is inferred from (a) the oxidation state of the metal and (b) the ligands on the copper.  So copper(II) with four negative charged chloride ligands would be "tetrachlorocopper(II)", although since the latter is an anion, it is often called "tetrachlorocuprate(II)", e.g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuprate).